# How to display pg_query results in a table using PHP?

Tags: php, sql, html-table

I'm trying to display the results of my query in a neatly formatted table but I'm pretty new to PHP so I'm at a bit of a loss. Currently I have this:

```
$dbconn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=mary");
$result =  pg_query($dbconn, $selectStmt);
$resultArr = pg_fetch_all($result);
print_r($resultArr);
```

Assume `$selectStmt = SELECT State, Name FROM perez.pop WHERE Name LIKE '%Alabama%';`
When I print this, I get the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [state] => 1 [name] => Alabama ) )
```

How could I place this into a table where the columns are "state" and "name" along with one more column in which I plan to place a link to a different page?

Also, can anyone clarify how the `$resultArr` looks when I get multiple rows as a result of my query?

EDIT: I'd like the output to look something like this:

```
State       | Name        | Follow link
___________________________________________________
32          Alabama       <some link to a php page> 
2           Alabama       <another link>
```

Comment: Why don't you try yourself ? And use `foreach loop` to display your data in table.

Comment: I've tried using a foreach loop but the only thing that displays when I try foreach($resultArr as $value){echo $value;} is "Array". Why is it only printing out the word "Array"?

Comment: It is obvious. you need to specify which value you need to display. `$value['state']`. Also it will be great if you edit your question with your expected output.

Answer (score 6):

You can just **loop** in your array and print your table while looping, something like

```
$resultArr = pg_fetch_all($result);
//print_r($resultArr);

echo '<table>
        <tr>
         <td>State</td>
         <td>Name</td>
        </tr>';

foreach($resultArr as $array)
{
    echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $array['State'].'</td>
            <td>'. $array['Name'].'</td>
          </tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = pg_query("SELECT * FROM user");
$users_arr = pg_fetch_all($query);

// render thead
$thead = '<thead>
    <tr>';
        foreach($users_arr[0] as $key => $value) {
        $thead .= '<th>' . $key . '</th>';
        }
        $thead .= '</tr>
</thead>';

// render tbody
$tbody = '<tbody>';
    foreach($users_arr as $key => $value) {
    $tbody .= '<tr>';
        foreach($value as $k => $v) {
        $tbody .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
        }
        $tbody .= '</tr>';
    }
    $tbody .= '</tbody>';

// render table
$table = '<table>' . $thead . $tbody . '</table>';
echo $table;
```